# Cant adjust the alignment of card in html used in django

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I added these lines in an HTML to render some posts and comments in the front end but if I post more than one post the alignment of post card got unsystematic . One card went bigger one got smaller how to fix the size for every post.

```
{

    % for post in posts %}
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                      <!-- ROW -->
                      <div class="row ">
              
                          <div class="col-12 mb-2">
                              <div id = "clicked-post" class="card shadow-sm">
                    <div class="card-body">
                          <div class="card-title">
                              <h5>{{ post.title }} <br> Posted by: {{ post.created_by }} &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp; {% if post.created_by == user %}<a href="{% url 'delete_post' post_id=post.id %}">Delete</a> {% endif %} </h5> 
                          <h6>Posted at: {{post.created_at}}[UTC 0]</h6>
                      </div>
                      <div class="card-main">
                          {{post.description}}
                      </div>


                      <div class="card-body">
                        <form  action="{% url 'create_comment' post.pk %}" method="post">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                {{ comment_form.comment_text|attr:"class:form-control rounded-pill"|attr:"placeholder:Add a class comment" }}
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <button class=" btn btn-circle" type="submit" id="button-addon2"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                      

                    <div class="card-body">
                        {% for comment in contents %}
                            {% if comment.post == post %}
                            <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                                <p class='ml-2'><strong>{{ comment.user }}</strong>: {{ comment.comment_text}}</p>
                            </div>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>

              </div>
                </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              {% endfor %}
```

Comment: You need to reproduce the output through static HTML and CSS so that you can get some help here.

Comment: can you tell me the process?

Comment: Use Codepen or Stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

Try aligning your divs via spacing or tabs so that you can see visually if you have failed to close one.  It looks like you failed to close your initial div class="card-body"

```
<div class="col-lg-9">
    <!-- ROW -->
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-12 mb-2">
            <div id = "clicked-post" class="card shadow-sm">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-title">
                        <h5>{{ post.title }} <br> Posted by: {{ post.created_by }} &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp; {% if post.created_by == user %}<a href="{% url 'delete_post' post_id=post.id %}">Delete</a> {% endif %} </h5> 
                        <h6>Posted at: {{post.created_at}}[UTC 0]</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-main">
                        {{post.description}}
                    </div>
<!-- you may need an extra </div> here  to close your div -->
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form  action="{% url 'create_comment' post.pk %}" method="post">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                {{ comment_form.comment_text|attr:"class:form-control rounded-pill"|attr:"placeholder:Add a class comment" }}
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <button class=" btn btn-circle" type="submit" id="button-addon2"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        {% for comment in contents %}
                            {% if comment.post == post %}
                            <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                                <p class='ml-2'><strong>{{ comment.user }}</strong>: {{ comment.comment_text}}</p>
                            </div>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```